# Failed to connect to local azure cosmosdb emulator

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I installed the [Azure CosmosDB Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator) on my Win10 computer, and I have the visibility of the launching page :

[image]

But when I try to connect to the database throught Robo3T or command line it doesn't work. I use the following cmd :

```
mongo mongodb://localhost:foofoojf5%2FR%2Bob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM%2B4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw%2FJw%3D%3D@localhost:10255/admin?ssl=true
```

And I got the following issue :

> 2019-07-18T14:33:27.265+0200 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:10255 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
>   2019-07-18T14:33:27.266+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server localhost:10255, connection attempt failed :
>   connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
>   @(connect):1:6
>   exception: connect failed

It is locally so I assume there is no port issue. Is it possible to be something related to the local certificat or my compagnie firewall ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I connected mongo emulator with ROBO3T tool, please see my configuration.

Firstly, get the emulator connection string from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#azure-cosmos-dbs-api-for-mongodb).

> mongodb://localhost:C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==@localhost:10255/admin?ssl=true

Then create the connect configuration:

**Connection:**

[image]

**Authentication**:

[image]

**SSL:**

[image]

**Click Test button:**

[image]

UI:

[image]

Comment: `Cannot connect to the MongoDB at localhost:10255.

Error:
SSL tunnel failure: Network is unreachable or SSL connection rejected by server. Reason: couldn't connect to server localhost:10255, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to localhost:10255 (127.0.0.1:10255) :: caused by :: no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`

Comment: You were right, but in order to do it you need to launch CosmosDb Emulator in cmd line with the following argument : `CosmosDB.Emulator.exe /EnableMongoDbEndpoint` Bounty for you

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. I was using  /EnableMongoDbEndpoint=3.6 which Robo 3T v1.3 did not like. Changing this to simply /EnableMongoDbEndpoint (which stepped down to 3.2) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, to interact Azure CosmosDb API for MongoDb we need to create a dedicated new folder under %localappdata%\CosmosDbEmulator and enable MongoDb endpoint v3.6 (*see below PowerShell command in **Step 1***).

> **Note:** *For any reason if CosmosDb emulator is reset to default folder path %localappdata%\CosmosDbEmulator (or) fail to connect in Robo 3T
> then always execute the below PowerShell script in **Step 1** once again.*

> **Note:** *From Robo 3T v1.4 onwards we don't have SSL tab in connection
> Settings dialog. Instead we have a tab TLS.*

```
1. Download and install Azure CosmosDb Emulator from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator?tabs=powershell%2Cssl-netstd21
2. Download and install Robo 3T (1.4.2 or latest) from https://robomongo.org/download
3. To show Azure CosmosDb emulator related database(s) in Robo 3T client app

Step 1
- Launch Azure CosmosDb Emulator 
  (Optional: Just to check CosmosDbEmulator is started successfully)
- Open Powershell as administrator and execute below commands
```

```ps
  # PowerShell Script
  # Change directory to default location where CosmosDb emulator is installed.
  cd\
  cd '.\Program Files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator\'
             
  # [Optional] If any cosmosDb emulator instance is running then shutdown
  .\Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /shutdown
        
  # To interact Azure CosmosDb API for MongoDb, create a new folder "<MongoDb>" under 
  # %localappdata%\CosmosDbEmulator and enable MongoDb endpoint v3.6
  .\Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /DataPath="$env:localappdata\CosmosDBEmulator\MongoDb" /EnableMongoDbEndpoint=3.6
```

```
Step 2      
- Now CosmosDb emulator will be successfully started,
  and launches the URL https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html in the browser
- Note down MongoDb connection string details from browser which will be required 
  while creating new Robo 3T connection. The default MongoDb connection string format is 
  mongodb://username:password@host:port/[database]?ssl=true
    - Username: localhost
    - Password (Primary Key): C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==
    - Port: 10255
    - Database: admin
    
Step 3
- Launch Robo 3T
- Click on Create new connection 
- In "Connection" tab
    - Provide Name of the connection as "<CosmosDbEmulator>"
    - Add port number as 10255
        
- In "Authentication" tab provide details noted down in previous Step 2
    - Check "Perform authentication"
    - Add Database as "admin"
    - Add Username as "https://localhost:8081"
    - Add Password as "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw=="
        
- In "TLS" tab provide
    - Check "Use TLS protocol"
    - From Authentication Method dropdown select "Self-signed Certificate"
        
- Click on "Test" button. 
    - It should successfully connects to localhost:10255 via TLS tunnel
    - It should successfully authorise to database "admin"
    
- Click on "Save" button    
- Click on "Connect" button. 
    - It will show the admin database and its related collections.
```